# why Kotlin inline function params is must not be null

Tags: kotlin, lambda, inline

[image]

```
inline fun <T, R> isNullObject(value: T?, notNullBlock: (T) -> R, isNullBlock: (() -> Unit)? = null) {

if (value != null) {
    notNullBlock(value)
} else {
    if(isNullBlock != null){
        isNullBlock()
    }
}
```

}

I tried to write some higher-order functions to facilitate development, but it is error

Comment: Btw, the type `R` is not needed in your code

Comment: why say that? R is result.isn't?

Comment: But the result is never used in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is related to how [`inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) and lambdas passed to it are inlined. The inline modifier affects both the function itself and the lambdas passed to it: all of those will be inlined into the call site. It seems Kotlin doesn't allow to use **nullable** lambdas.

If you want some default value for `isNullBlock` parameter you can use empty braces `isNullBlock: () -> Unit = {}`:

```
inline fun <T, R> isNullObject(value: T?, notNullBlock: (T) -> R, isNullBlock: () -> Unit = {}) {

    if (value != null) {
        notNullBlock(value)
    } else {
        isNullBlock()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*There is a [great post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/inline-functions-under-the-hood-12ddcc0b3a56) explaining how `inline` works from Android Developer Advocate Florina Muntenescu. Following all of the explanations it should be clear why nullable lambdas are not allowed.*

In short:

> Because of the `inline` keyword, the compiler copies the content of the inline function to the call site, avoiding creating a new `Function` object.

That is the performance benefit inline keyword gives us. But in order to do that compiler must be sure that you always pass in a lambda argument whether it is empty or not. When you try to make the lambda argument nullable compiler will not be able to copy the content of a `null` lambda to the call site. Similarly, you cannot execute compare operations like `!= null` or use `?` to unwrap the optional lambda that should be inlined **because when compiled there will be no lamda/function objects**. More explanation below.

#### Example (long explanation)

In my examples your function is updated and takes empty lambda as default arguments for `isNullBlock`:

```
inline fun <T, R> isNullObject(value: T?, notNullBlock: (T) -> R, isNullBlock: (() -> Unit) = {}) {
    if (value != null) {
        notNullBlock(value)
    } else {
        isNullBlock()
    }
}
```

Here is usage of **not inlined** version of your `isNullObject` function decompiled to Java.

Kotlin code

```
class Test {
    init {
        isNullObject(null as? Int,
            {
                println("notNullBlock called")
                it
            },
            { println("isNullBlock called") })
        isNullObject(0, 
            {
                println("notNullBlock called")
                it
            },
            { println("isNullBlock called") })
    }
}
```

Decompiled Java code

```
public final class Test {
   public Test() {
      TestKt.isNullObject((Integer)null, (Function1)null.INSTANCE, (Function0)null.INSTANCE);
      TestKt.isNullObject(0, (Function1)null.INSTANCE, (Function0)null.INSTANCE);
   }
}
```

As you can see nothing too unusual happens (though, it is hard to understand what `null.INSTANCE` is). Your `isNullObject` function called with three arguments passed as defined in Kotlin.

Here is how your **inlined** function will decompile using the same Kotlin code.

```
public final class Test {
   public Test() {
      Object value$iv = (Integer)null;
      int $i$f$isNullObject = false;
      int var3 = false;
      String var4 = "isNullBlock called";
      boolean var5 = false;
      System.out.println(var4);
      int value$iv = false;
      $i$f$isNullObject = false;
      int var8 = false;
      String var9 = "notNullBlock called";
      boolean var6 = false;
      System.out.println(var9);
   }
}
```

For the first function call, we immediately get `if (value != null)` statement resolved as `false` and `notNullBlock` passed in is not even ended up in the final code. At runtime, there will be no need to check each time if the value is null or not. Because the `isNullObject` is inlined with its lambdas there is no `Function` objects generated for lambda arguments. It means there is nothing to check for nullability. Also, this is the reason why *you cannot hold a reference to the lambda/function arguments of the inlined function*.

```
Object value$iv = (Integer)null;
int $i$f$isNullObject = false;
int var3 = false;
String var4 = "isNullBlock called";
boolean var5 = false;
System.out.println(var4);
```

But inlining works only if compiler is able to get values of given arguments **at compile time**. If instead of `isNullObject(null as? Int, ...)` and `isNullObject(0, ...)` the first argument was a function call - inlining would give no benefit!

#### When compiler cannot resolve if statement

A function added - `getValue()`. Returns optional `Int`. The compiler does not know the result of `getValue()` call ahead of time as it can be calculated only at runtime. Thus inlining does only one thing - copies full content of the `isNullObject` into `Test` class constructor and does it twice, for each function call. There is a benefit still - we get rid of 4 `Function`s instances created at runtime to hold the content of each lambda argument.

Kotlin

```
class Test {
    init {
        isNullObject(getValue(),
            {
                println("notNullBlock called")
                it
            },
            { println("isNullBlock called") })
        isNullObject(getValue(),
            {
                println("notNullBlock called")
                it
            },
            { println("isNullBlock called") })
    }

    fun getValue(): Int? {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0L) {
            return 0
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Decompiled Java

```
public Test() {
      Object value$iv = this.getValue();
      int $i$f$isNullObject = false;
      int it;
      boolean var4;
      String var5;
      boolean var6;
      boolean var7;
      String var8;
      boolean var9;
      if (value$iv != null) {
         it = ((Number)value$iv).intValue();
         var4 = false;
         var5 = "notNullBlock called";
         var6 = false;
         System.out.println(var5);
      } else {
         var7 = false;
         var8 = "isNullBlock called";
         var9 = false;
         System.out.println(var8);
      }

      value$iv = this.getValue();
      $i$f$isNullObject = false;
      if (value$iv != null) {
         it = ((Number)value$iv).intValue();
         var4 = false;
         var5 = "notNullBlock called";
         var6 = false;
         System.out.println(var5);
      } else {
         var7 = false;
         var8 = "isNullBlock called";
         var9 = false;
         System.out.println(var8);
      }

   }
```